# Issue running sample program (calc.y) with racc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get racc to work with ruby. I've successfully run:

```
$ ruby setup.rb config --without-ext
$ ruby setup.rb setup
$ ruby setup.rb install
```

However, when I try to use racc to process a grammar, I get the following errors:

```
$ racc -o calc calc.y

/Users/rajeshchawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/racc:301:in `<class:RaccTableFile>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/Users/rajeshchawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/racc:301:in `<class:RaccTableFile>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/Users/rajeshchawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/racc:99:in `get_options': undefined method `map' for #<String:0x007fa22290eae0> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/rajeshchawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/racc:25:in `racc_main'
    from /Users/rajeshchawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/racc:527:in `<main>'
```

Thoughts / suggestions appreciated.

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this site is out of date and the correct way to get racc is using a gem. The version that works for me (as a gem) is 1.4.12. The runtime for racc is already included in the distribution.

Regards,
Rajesh